# ImageField() not saving images in ModelForm - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I try to upload a picture from my form, everything processes, but the image is not being saved.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks ahead of time!

***models.py:***

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'category')
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.user)
```

***views.py:***

```
def photo_upload_view(request, username):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you! You have successfully posted your picture!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PhotoUploadForm()

    submit_btn = "Upload Post"

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "submit_btn": submit_btn
    }
    return render(request, "photos/photo_upload.html", context)
```

***forms.py:***

```
class PhotoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('user', 'category', 'title', 'description', 'image')
```

***.html:***

```
<form method='POST' action='{{ action_url }}'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input class='btn btn-default {{ submit_btn_class }}' type='submit' value='{{ submit_btn }}'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should add the [`enctype=multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) attribute to the `<form>` tag:

```
<form method='POST' action='{{ action_url }}' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Answer (score 3):

except for adding `enctype=multipart/form-data`, another possible reason that your image is not saving in `modelform` can be adding `request.FILES` in your `POST` condition:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ProjectCreateForm(request.POST, instance=project)
```

should be:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ProjectCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project)
```

Answer (score 0):

data.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

use request.FILES